# Remove new lines in rows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Seem to have an issue with some rows in my database from when I was manually copy/pasting data from excell into phpmyadmin the fields also copied new lines in. When I export the database and open it with Notepad it shows as

```
"1181","975","19",NULL,"193.xxx.xxx.79","02:00:00:20:a1:79
","255.255.255.0","193.xxx.xxx.1","24",NULL,NULL,"net0"
"1967","1708","19",NULL,"193.xxx.xxx.64
","02:00:00:20:a1:64
","255.255.255.0","193.xxx.xxx.1","24",NULL,NULL,"net0"
```

Should be

```
"1181","975","19",NULL,"193.xxx.xxx.79","02:00:00:20:a1:79","255.255.255.0","193.xxx.xxx.1","24",NULL,NULL,"net0"
"1967","1708","19",NULL,"193.xxx.xxx.64","02:00:00:20:a1:64","255.255.255.0","193.xxx.xxx.1","24",NULL,NULL,"net0"
```

Line 2 should not be here

[image]

How can I fix this via either a sql query or linux command. Every row ends in `"net0"` - Note that some rows have two lines in them

Comment: Are you sure it's a newline and not a space where notepad decides to add a line break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about fixing data that is already in the database, then you could just use the `REPLACE()` function in an `UPDATE` statement, something like this:

```
UPDATE
  YourTable
SET
  Col1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(Col1, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
, Col2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(Col2, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
...
;
```

where `YourTable` is the name of the table containing the corrupted data and `Col1`, `Col2` etc. are the names of the columns that might – yet should not – have new lines in their values.

The use of two separate nested `REPLACE` calls might be unnecessary.  If you know for certain that all the new lines have the same format (as well as which one), you could use a single `REPLACE` with a corresponding new line encoding, depending on the platform:

- `REPLACE(ColName, CHAR(13, 10), '')` for Windows
- `REPLACE(ColName, CHAR(13), '')` for Mac
- `REPLACE(ColName, CHAR(10), '')` for Unix

Doing it with two individual replacements is just more flexible as it covers all the possibilities.

Comment: That might toss the other newlines, too!

Comment: @RickJames: I did stipulate that the columns being updated should be those that aren't supposed to have new lines.